# Optimizing my data structure. Dealing with lots of units and conversions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

My website deals with a lot of drug doses and units. Currently it is setup where it's not really flexible to mold those doses and units into different values based on a user.

For instance, if a user submits a record where he took 1ml of alcohol on monday, 10ml on tuesday, and 2liters on tuesday then the same substance users two sepester units. So what happens if I want to show the user the average of these three days ONLY in mL? What about if the users want's to see it in only Liters?

Here's what I have so far.

```
 drugs
 id | drug
 1  | alcohol
 2  | cannabis


 units
 id | unit
 1  | ml
 2  | mg
 3  | g
 4  | l


 unit_conversion
 id | from_unitid | to_unitid | multiplier
 1  | 1           | 4         | 1000
 2  | 4           | 1         | .001
 3  | 2           | 3         | 1000
 4  | 3           | 2         | .001

 user_dose_line
 id | drug_id | unit_id | dose
 1  | 1       | 1       | 100
 2  | 1       | 1       | 200
 3  | 1       | 4       | 1
```

Here's how i'd ideals want it to work.

A user submits a record. He fills out that the drug is alcohol, the dose is 100, and the unit is ml. This stores in the data base table is id#1 on user_dose_line.

Now let's say there is another table. It is the options table where the user sets what default unit of measurement he wants to use.

```
 user_dose_options
 id | user_id | drug_id | unit_id
 1  | 22      | 1       | 4
```

This shows that the user has selected that any entry with alcohol in it, should always be converted to liters.

Here is my problem, where in my logic do I do these conversions.

I use CAKEPHP which is a usual MVC framework. Should I be doing the conversion in the model? in the controller? What is the best practice for this. And am I choose the most optimized route for this?

I plan to later add a lot more functionality for units/doses and thus I need my database setup in the most efficient way to allow me to do lots of cool calculations with the data (display graphics, statistics, etc)

Comment: consider marking one of the answers as accepted so people will know this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an input and an output method. Those should convert from the input unit to one standard unit which you use to store the data.
You could do this in the setter of your model.
i.e.

```
class userInTake {

  private $userId; 
  private $drugId;
  private $dose;

  public function setDrugUse($drugId,$dose,$unitId) {
    // $convert dose to you default unit for this drug
    $this->dose   = yourConversionMethod($dose,$unit,$desiredUnit);
    $this->userId = $userId;
    $this->drugId = $drugId;
  }
  ...
}
```

At the point where you store the user input into your models, you do the conversion.
So, if for instance, a user inputs he took 4l of alcohol on monday, you convert the litres to ml and then store the ml value.
so if a user inouts three occasions, monday 4l, tuesday 40ml, friday 2,4l, you convert each input to ml.
When displaying the average, you'll get 6440ml.

Your output function could choose the unit that serves best to display the value (i.e. if a ml value > 10000, display as litres).

This way you don't have to store different units and only need your units for conversion upon input/output. That should make calculations a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: How do I determine what the one standard unit should be? There will be many drugs, and many units. ml, mg, l, g, mcg, ng, oz, etc. So how do I determine which standard unit it should be converted to for the database? Should I set the standard unit per each individual drug?

Comment: @user3196108 * Should I set the standard unit per each individual drug?* Yes, i think you should. Meassuring alcohol in ml makes a lot more sense than meassuring it in g right? So just pick the metric system, choose the lowest unit that still makes sense (you might not be interested in nanolitre amounts of alcohol).

Answer (score 0):

The ideal setting is that any operation related to data should be in the model. You can override the `afterFind()` method to do the conversion right after the query, and have the data ready to use.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind

Remember the philosophy: Fat models, skinny controllers.